# Debug sent headers by FormRequest.from_response

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Scrapy has great debugging feature. However I not able to find way to debug the headers, get, post param sent by FormRequest.from_response

Is there any way, I can see those post data? I am particularly concern if it send values from hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom `FormRequest`

```
from scrapy import FormRequest


class MyOwnFormRequest(FormRequest):

    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        # debug here
        super(MyOwnFormRequest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # debug here too


...
def start_requests():
    yield MyOwnFormRequest(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the method that handles the response to your `FormRequest` object you can inspect the request headers originally sent from `response.request.headers`.

For example:

```py
>>> response.request.headers
{b'Accept': [b'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'], b'Accept-Language': [b'en'], b'User-Agent': [b'Scrapy/1.5.2 (+https://scrapy.org)'], b'Accept-Encoding': [b'gzip,deflate']}
```